# dotnetnuke hide menu from page

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm running a dotnetnuke project (v7.0) with 2 portals.

I need to remove the default DDR menu from one page only. 
The menu works great now with multiple pages and sub-pages, however on 1 specific page , ie landing page, I don't want to show the menu.

Right now I can think of 2 methods for achieving this:

- Create a new skin template, remove menu, apply template to that one page
- Use jquery to detect URL, for that page hide menu.

I'd rather just code the logic inside the template file, but I'm not strong in .net/c# and I'm new to DNN.

Answer (score 0):

It's just one page today.

However, if you are using it for a landing page design I would recommend you just create another skin and exclude it from that and tailor that skin for that need.

That way when your non-technical editors need to work on the site and make a page that might only be used when linking from Google Adwords or whatever they can pick a template without that navigation and you as the developer/designer don't need to edit the skin to put in another exception based on the URL.